# Angular.js - search filter for object with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm apologizing for messy description of my problem. I hope you understand it.
I have this HTML code:

```
 <form>
    <input ng-model="attr.query" type="text" placeholder="{{attr.attr_name}}" ng-repeat="attr in attrs">
 </form>
 <table>                
   <tr ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in element">{{value}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

JS controller:

```
$scope.attrs = [{'descr':'descr1'},{'descr':'descr2'}];
$scope.elements = [{'property1" : 'value1', 'property2' : 'value2'},{'property1" : 'value3', 'property2' : 'value4'}];
```

I need to filter each  by query from input. But i need to filter only  with the same attr as in input field.

[image]

I have some troubles to apply filter to array of objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (I don't have enough rep to ask in a comment, sorry), you want to filter the data on one or more of several attributes.

The simplest way to do this is probably by defining a custom filter function accessible to your scope. AngularJS's `filter` filter [will happily accept](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) that as an evaluator.

```
$scope.customFilter = function(item) {
    var passed = true;
    if(/* the item doesn't pass muster */) {
        passed = false;
    }
    return passed;
}
```

If it helps, I put together [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blangenfeld/VeuKf/) to demonstrate. (NB. The query fields are case-sensitive.)